# Apache Beam Join extension throwing Method call expected error

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Here is the code:

```
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.joinlibrary.*;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.joinlibrary.Join.*;

public class innerJoinBeamPractise {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create();

      PCollection<String> indata = pipeline.apply(TextIO.read().from("./data/indata.csv"));

      PCollection<KV<String,String>>  dataCollection1 = indata.apply( ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, KV<String,String>>() {

          @ProcessElement
          public void processElement(@Element String line, OutputReceiver<KV<String,String>> out) {
              String[] arr = line.split(",");
//              KV<String,String> keyedData = KV.of(arr[0] ,String.join(",", arr));
              KV<String,String> keyedData = KV.of(arr[0] , arr[1] );

              System.out.println(keyedData);
              out.output(keyedData);

      }}
      ));


            PCollection<KV<String,String>>  dataCollection2 = indata.apply( ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, KV<String,String>>() {

                   @ProcessElement
                   public void processElement(@Element String line, OutputReceiver<KV<String,String>> out) {
                       String[] arr = line.split(",");
            //              KV<String,String> keyedData = KV.of(arr[0] ,String.join(",", arr));
                       KV<String,String> keyedData2 = KV.of(arr[0] , arr[6] );

                       System.out.println(keyedData2);
                       out.output(keyedData2);

                   }}
            )) ;

      PCollection<KV<String,KV<String,String>>> joinedData = Join.InnerJoin(dataCollection1,dataCollection2);

      pipeline.run();

  }
}
```

This code is not compiling and I am getting Method call expected error at Join.InnerJoin(dataCollection1,dataCollection2);

I am following the doc : https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/joinlibrary/Join.html but could not able to figure out the issue.

Can someone please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: It is `innerJoin` not `InnerJoin` (lower case `i`)

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you. It's compiling  now.